# Display to output port in a recursive procedure - Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, mit-scheme

I am learning Scheme and want to write a recursive procedure which output to the console in each run level:

```
(define (dummy count)
    (if (= 0 count)        
        (runtime)
        ((display "test" console-i/o-port) (dummy (- count 1)))))
```

And then test with:

```
(dummy 10)
```

But it appears that only the output of the last procedure called will be printed out.
What should I do to make it happen? Thanks. (I am using Mit-scheme)

Comment: And what exactly do you want to display? the current value of count? Or the word "test" `count` number of times?

Comment: Yeah, just the word "test". It doesn't matter right. I just wanna know why only one word "test" printed out.

Comment: Good, take a look at my answer below, it does just that, in a simple way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
((display "test" console-i/o-port) (dummy (- count 1)))
```

This is a function call where `(display "test" console-i/o-port)` is the function that's supposed to be called and `(dummy (- count 1))` is the argument to that function. Since `(display "test" console-i/o-port) does not actually return a function, this will cause an error (after printing test).

To do what you actually want to do (first execute `(display ...)` and then execute `(dummy ...)`), you can use the `begin` form like this:

```
(begin (display "test" console-i/o-port) (dummy (- count 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for ur ans. So in scheme, everything of this construct (A B C..D), A must be such that A is a function and the rests are arguments. Why I still see in the SCIP book programs like ((print a)(print b))?.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is displaying "test" `count` number of times (10 in the example) you can do something like this (assuming that `count` is positive):

```
(define (dummy count)
  (if (> count 0)
      (begin 
        (display "test" console-i/o-port)
        (dummy (- count 1)))))
```